# clang -coverage marks function signatures as not covered

Tags: c, clang, llvm, code-coverage, lcov

I'm trying to use `clang -coverage` to generate coverage information for my C project, but all the function signatures are marked as not covered, when I'd expect them to be not instrumented at all.

Small example -- this file is `hello.c`:

```
extern int puts(const char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  puts("hello, world");
  return 0;
}
```

In this example, I'd expect lines 4 and 5 to be marked executable, but not line 3. I run `clang -coverage` and `lcov` like this to get initial coverage:

```
$ cc -coverage hello.c
$ lcov -c -i -d . -o coverage.base
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version: 3.6.0
Found LLVM gcov version 3.4, which emulates gcov version 4.2
Scanning . for .gcno files ...
Found 1 graph files in .
Processing hello.gcno
Finished .info-file creation
```

The generated coverage file looks like this:

```
TN:
SF:/Users/isbadawi/cov/hello.c
FN:3,main
FNDA:0,main
FNF:1
FNH:0
DA:3,0
DA:4,0
DA:5,0
LF:3
LH:0
end_of_record
```

I'd expect the `DA:3,0` line not to be there -- or at least, if it's there, I'd expect it to be marked covered in the final coverage report. When I go on to run `a.out` and run lcov again to generate a full coverage report, like this:

```
$ ./a.out
$ lcov -q -c -d . -o coverage.run
$ lcov -q -d . -a coverage.base -a coverage.run -o coverage.total
```

`coverage.total` looks like this:

```
TN:
SF:/Users/isbadawi/cov/hello.c
FN:3,main
FNDA:1,main
FNF:1
FNH:1
DA:3,0
DA:4,1
DA:5,1
LF:3
LH:2
end_of_record
```

I end up with 66.7% coverage instead of 100%. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the system clang on OS X Yosemite:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Trying the same thing with gcc (tried with 4.8.2), the line is still marked executable, but the final coverage report has it being executed.

Answer (score 0):

The code the compiler generates doesn't always correspond directly with your lines of code.  This may be the problem here.  I experienced a similar frustration when LCOV would report no coverage on the *closing brace* of a block (function or otherwise), e.g.:

```
if (x < lim) {
  process_x(x);
  ++x_processed;
} // <== this line is listed as NOT COVERED
```

So, the way around it was to use LCOV keyword markers.  In this case:

```
if (x < lim) {
  process_x(x);
  ++x_processed;
} // LCOV_EXCL_LINE
```

If you use the above marker on your line 3, that should fix your reporting issue.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   // LCOV_EXCL_LINE
```

There are corresponding markers to exclude a range of lines, as well as excluding branch coverage for a line or range of lines.  Check out the `geninfo` manpage for complete details.  Here's an online version:  http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/geninfo.1.php

Note:  These keywords can share the line with meaningful comments (i.e., they don't have to stand alone on the line in order to function properly).

Answer (score 0):

This bug should be fixed in Clang 8.